# android listview id combination

Tags: android, listview

I have a table with 3 fields, id and topic and contents, id is the primary key.
1) display the topics in a listview, using adapter fill the data from the query result
then 2) if user click on topic, display the corresponding content by query the id in the db.(since the topic may be duplicated, so id is the one to query db. and since the records may be deleted, so the id may not the same as the position)

question is:
how to combine the id in the first list item? Easy to get it but did not display it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you bind the data to the `ListView`, a simple adapter or a cursor adapter?

Comment: please post your adapter class.

Comment: you can refer my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475636/how-to-get-rowid-of-custom-listviews-selected-rows-child/9476638#9476638

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar in the app I'm currently finishing up. The big difference is I don't let the user delete or add to the database. So it allows me to getpositioninview() to call the next table and get a cursor based of that selection. First I would recommend make your db two tables. One that has topics and another that has your contents. In your content table add a column for "top id". You then need to setup a method with your onclicklistener to get the position in cursor of item clicked and save it's id to a string. Use that ID to filter your cursor to grab the contents you need.

```
 public Cursor getSource()
          {
             return myDataBase.query(SOURCE_TABLE, new String[]{
                    KEY_ID, KEY_SOURCEDESC, KEY_CATEGORY,},
                    KEY_CATEGORY+ "=" + categories.categoryClick, null, null, null, KEY_SOURCEDESC);
          }
```

In my above code KEY_CATEGORY would be your topic key. categories.categoryClick would be the value of ID you saved.